# Using PyperClip on web app

Tags: python, pyperclip

I am using pyperclip.py to grab a list of E-Mail Addresses in my web app using a form so a user can paste it locally via clipboard. It works perfect locally. However, while running it on a server (Linux 14.04 with Apache2) and accessed from a client system through the browser it doesn't copy. How can I get it to copy to the clipboard of the client's system?

Right now I'm just trying to get it to work and as such I'm only using a single line. I'm using pyperclip 1.5.15 with xclip and Python 3.4. The server is running Linux 14.04 and the client has noticed issues on Windows 8 and Windows 10 using Google Chrome and IE. No other os has currently been tested.

```
pyperclip.copy("HELLO")
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I couldn't find many details on this subject I thought I'd answer my question. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that browsers will support pyperclip so an HTML + Javascript work around is required (meaning on pyperclip). First, add your Django Template var as an HTML attribute from there you can use Javascript to handle the copy functionality. Below is an example of how to do this, sorry in advance because stackoverflow was giving some weird formatting to the example. It also assumes you have a form below with the id of email_list_clipboard. I hope this helps anyone else who may of run into a similar issue!

Example:

```
    <html email-list="{{request.session.email_list}}">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
                var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

                // Place in top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
                textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
                textArea.style.top = 0;
                textArea.style.left = 0;

                textArea.style.width = '2em';
                textArea.style.height = '2em';

                // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
                textArea.style.padding = 0;

                textArea.style.border = 'none';
                textArea.style.outline = 'none';
                textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';

                textArea.style.background = 'transparent';

                textArea.value = text;

                document.body.appendChild(textArea);

                textArea.select();

                try {
                    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
                    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
                }

                document.body.removeChild(textArea);
            }

            // set things up so my function will be called when field_three changes
            $('#email_list_clipboard').click(function (click) {
                event.preventDefault();
                copyTextToClipboard(document.documentElement.getAttribute("email-list"));
    });

</script>
```